# Linking a static library into Boost Python (shared library) - Import Error

Tags: c++, python, boost, linker, compilation

I am building a Boost Python module (.so shared library file) which depends on another external library (STXXL)

While I can build and import the example Boost Python modules, I run into problems when STXXL is thrown into the mix.  Specifically when running `import fast_parts` in python

I get `ImportError: ./fast_parts.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5stxxl10ran32StateE`

This says to me that the STXXL library isn't being linked, but I am not sure how that could be as I am linking against it and the linker isn't giving me any errors.  It's worth noting I can successfully build and run standalone programs using STXXL and as far as I know the libraries are stored in a .a archive in the lib directory shown below.  I have reduced my Makefile down to a single command as follows:

`g++ -I/home/zenna/Downloads/stxxl-1.3.0/include -include stxxl/bits/defines.h -I/home/zenna/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE  -O3 -Wall -g -DFOO=BAR -pthread -L/home/zenna/Downloads/stxxl-1.3.0/lib/ -lstxxl -L/home/zenna/local/lib/ -lboost_python -lpython2.6 -fPIC -shared -o fast_parts.so partition.cpp`

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming Linux, please comment if this is incorrect. What does the `ldd` output for `libfast_parts.so` look like? Does it indicate `libstxxl.so` is not found?

You might need to add `/home/zenna/Downloads/stxxl-1.3.0/lib/` in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or the rpath for `libfast_parts.so`.

```
-Wl,-rpath,/home/zenna/Downloads/stxxl-1.3.0/lib -L/home/zenna/Downloads/stxxl-1.3.0/lib -lstxxl
```

Comment: so fast_parts.so is the final output module.  the ldd for it does not require libstxxl.so as libstxxl doesn't exist, the only file that does exist is stxxl.a which is a archive of .o static library files.  It seems the missing symbol in question  _ZN5stxxl10ran32StateE is contained with a file rand.libstxxl.o contained within the archive (found using the nm tool), but when this does not show up when I run nm on the actual archive.  I'm not sure if that's relevant

Comment: Actually that's not true

nm on fast_parts showed 

fast_part.so:0001eec0 t _GLOBAL__I__ZN5stxxl10ran32StateE

Comment: something looks strange about your link link, you might want to play around with the ordering of `-lstxxl` and whatever object files need symbols defined from it.