# When Linking: use -l flag or just treat archives as input

Tags: linker, compilation, shared-libraries

I had some problems linking the static library stxxl into a shared library as outlined in my question [Linking a static library into Boost Python (shared library) - Import Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518069/linking-a-static-library-into-boost-python-shared-library-import-error)

The command I was using was

```
g++ -Wall -pthread -march=i686 -I/home/zenna/Downloads/stxxl-1.3.0/include -include stxxl/bits/defines.h -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I /home/zenna/local/include/ -I /usr/include/python2.6/ -fPIC -c partition.cpp -o obj/Partition_wrap.o
```

and to link:

```
g++  -shared -lboost_python -L/home/zenna/local/lib/ -L/home/zenna/Downloads/stxxl-1.3.0/lib/bk/ -Wall -pthread -L/home/zenna/Downloads/stxxl-1.3.0/lib -lstxxl -o lib/fast_parts.so obj/Partition_wrap.o
```

Using nm I found the missing symbols was in the final output shared object library, but had type "U" for undefined.

I then changed the linking command to not only use -lstxxl but also add the entire archive file as another input to the linker

such that the new command was (difference at end)

++  -shared -lboost_python -L/home/zenna/local/lib/ -L/home/zenna/Downloads/stxxl-1.3.0/lib/bk/ -Wall -pthread -L/home/zenna/Downloads/stxxl-1.3.0/lib -lstxxl -o lib/fast_parts.so obj/Partition_wrap.o obj/libstxxl.a

This fixed the problem as far as I can tell.

My question is then **what is the difference between using the -l flag and adding the archive as an input and why did former method result in undefined symbols?**

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your case was that you specified -lstxxl before the object files. When you put `libstxxl.a` at the end, the symbols from it are read again and the undefined symbols are resolved. You could try moving it before `obj/Partition_wrap.o` and check if it will result in undefined symbols.

From `man ld`

> **ld -o  /lib/crt0.o hello.o -lc**
>
> This tells ld to produce a file called output as the result of linking the file "/lib/crt0.o" with "hello.o" and the library "libc.a",
>          which will come from the standard search directories.  (See the discussion of the -l option below.)
>
> Some of the command-line options to ld may be specified at any point in the command line.  However, **options which refer to files, such
>          as -l or -T, cause the file to be read at the point at which the option appears in the command line, relative to the object files and
>          other file options.**
>
> **Non-option arguments are object files or archives which are to be linked together**.  They may follow, precede, or be mixed in with
>          command-line options, except that an object file argument may not be placed between an option and its argument.
>
> **-l namespec**
>
> **The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it is specified on the command line.  If the archive defines a
>              symbol which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive on the command line, the linker will include the
>              appropriate file(s) from the archive.  However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing later on the command line will not cause
>              the linker to search the archive again.**

Although it's not mentioned very clear there doesn't seem to be any difference between the 2 ways of giving the linker the files to link.